# Which is the most accurate GPIO API for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio

According to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58825/42583, which is now nearly six years old,

> one unique feature of [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) is it times GPIO events at source so for any timing purpose pigpio is likely to be the most accurate.

In fact PIGPIO is what I've been using, and it indeed gave much better control of servos than whatever else I tried first.

Is it still the most accurate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of  any significant changes  in the intervening years.

The `sysfs` interface has been deprecated in  favour of the `gpiochip`  interface.  Any performance improvements seem to be marginal.  `gpiochip` does provide GPIO event timestamps.  Any improvement should be visible when used for decoding  DHT11/22 signals.  I measured little actual improvement in DHT11/22 decoding and `pigpio` still outperforms both `sysfs` and`gpiochip` in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is a meaningless concept here. All half dozen or so libraries in common use are accurate in that they do what they say on the box.

How they differ is in speed, overhead and convenience. E.g. pigpio uses a socket/pipe interface which imposes a significant overhead but allows the user access to functionality normally restricted to kernel code.

See [Controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO with c and Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117592/8697) for a review I did 2 years ago.

In practice I use many depending on the task in hand. E.g. pigpio is good for servos because it uses hardware timers and is unaffected by other tasks.